# Java & symbolic links in windows

Tags: java, windows

I've been playing with `java.nio.file.Files` and stumbled upon a strange issue. I have a symbolic link, but `Files.isSymbolicLink()` and symbolic link attribute of  `Files.readAttributes()` show different results.

Here's how I create the link:

```
D:\DEV\test>mklink /D link1 components
symbolic link created for link1 <<===>> components
```

Relevant java code:

```
Path symLinkDirectory = Paths.get("D:\\DEV\\test\\link1");
DosFileAttributes dosFileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(symLinkDirectory, DosFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println(String.format(
        "Files.isSymbolicLink(): %b, dosFileAttributes.isSymbolicLink(): %b", 
        Files.isSymbolicLink(symLinkDirectory), dosFileAttributes.isSymbolicLink()));
```

Gives me this output:

> Files.isSymbolicLink(): true, dosFileAttributes.isSymbolicLink(): false

Could anyone tell me why attributes report that the file is not a symbolic link? Am I missing something? Is this happening on unix too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add `LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS` to the invocation of readAttributes to get the attributes of the link itself instead of the link target.

```
DosFileAttributes dosFileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(symLinkDirectory,
                        DosFileAttributes.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that option.